# check checkbox on populated dropdown value selection [SQL-SERVER]

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, checkbox

got for this example 8 checkboxes:

```
 <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
    <tbody>


    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><strong>Technologie</strong></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec1</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technologie[Tec1]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec2</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="Technologie[Tec2]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec3</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technologie[Tec3]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"Tec4</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technologie[Tec4]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec5</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technologie[Tec5]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec6</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technologie[Tec6]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec7</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technologie[Tec7]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
   <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec8</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technologie[Tec8]" type="checkbox" value="2" /> </td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is the SQL Table for the poplated Dropdown:

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Tec_ID | Tec1 | Tec2 | Tec3 | Tec4 | Tec5 | Tec6 | Tec7 | Tec8 |RanNr |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|      1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 | 1353 |
|      2 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 | 0000 |
|      3 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    1 | 1353 |
|      4 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 | 1123 |
|      5 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    2 | 1353 |
|      6 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    2 | 1353 |
|      7 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 | 1993 |
|      8 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 | 1123 |
|      9 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 | 1353 |
|     10 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    2 | 1366 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

And here the PHP Part how i populate the Dropdown.

```
<select id="Tec_ID" name="Tec_ID" size="1" >    
                    <option disabled selected value> </option>;

            <?php
            foreach($connection->query($tec) as $m)
            {
                        if($m['Tec_ID'] == $_GET['Tec_ID']){
                $isSelected = 'selected="selected"';
            }else{
                $isSelected = '';
            }
            echo "<option value='" . $m['Tec_ID'] . "'".$isSelected."  >" .$m['RanNr'] ."</option>";
            }
            ?>
```

Notice the last Tec8 can be value 1 or 2.

**for ex.** You see already if I select Tec_ID 1. Tec1 and Tec5 Checkbox should be checked.

But atm I have no idea, how I can handle this in with Javascript/PHP/MSQLCode? Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I created the following PHP demo using the information you provided: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ffa32dbd5fd7db48057c0b7fa82cbd9d23b34ce

Which generated the following HTML (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/joxBbL):

```
<select id="Tec_ID" name="Tec_ID" size="1" >    
    <option disabled selected value> </option>;

    <option value='1'  >1353</option>
    <option value='2'  >0</option>
    <option value='3'  >1353</option>
    <option value='4'selected="selected"  >1123</option>
    <option value='5'  >1353</option>
    <option value='6'  >1353</option>
    <option value='7'  >1993</option>
    <option value='8'  >1123</option>
    <option value='9'  >1353</option>
    <option value='10'  >1366</option>
</select>
```

I'm not sure what you wanted to accomplish, but there is a dropdown with the `RanNr` variable of each `$tec`

(I do not have enough rep to comment but I will edit/remove this answer later)

Comment: yes but i populate the Dropdown with SQL querys from my SQL-Server. I wrote that, i cant do Arrays for each entry. And i have rly no idea what are you posted? I Asked when i select for example the first entry, the Checkbox 1 and 5 should be checked.